# How to automatically prepend parent figure label to subcaption's?

Tags: captions, subcaption

In this MWE, I would like to make the subcaption label be `Figure 0.1(a)` instead of `(a)`. In other words, I need the whole subcaption to be `Figure 0.1(a) some subcaption`.

Additionally, if the parent figure label changed, I need the subcaption one to change accordingly (e.g. `Fig 1` for the parent results in `Fig 1(a)` for the subfigure).

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \subcaption{some subcaption}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{some caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you mean `\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\thefigure.\alph{subfigure}}` perhaps?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer it results in `(0.1.a) some caption`.

Comment: Isn't that what you wanted? The parent is `0.1` so the child is `0.1` + `a`. Have you looked at the manuals for `caption` and `subcaption`? They have lots of documentation with plenty of examples.

Comment: @DiaaAbidou: Well, the parent figure is `0.1` since you don't have a chapter defined yet, and usually  `\thefigure` expands to `\thechapter.\arabic{figure}`, now for the example I gave above, the chapter counter is `0` yet, so the output is `(0.1.a)`

Comment: @cfr No, I need to prepend the parent figure label `Figure` to the subcaption's, i.e. I need the subcaption to be `Figure 0.1(a)` as I said in my question.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I am actually looking for how to prepend the parent label `Figure` to the subcaption's. I am OK with the figure number for now.

Comment: @DiaaAbidou: Your question is misleading, in my point of view

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I tried my best to explain what I need in the question body.

Comment: The manual of `caption` is a bit more helpful than `subcaption`, in my point of view

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `\DeclareCaptionFormat` command will help here, the `#1`, `#2` and `#3` are replaced by the caption label, the separator and the caption text, in this order.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}


\DeclareCaptionFormat{diaa}{\figurename~ \thefigure.#1 #2 #3}

\begin{document}



\captionsetup[subfigure]{format=diaa}
\chapter{Foo}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \subcaption{some subcaption}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{some caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update** With some 'parametrization' for the `\@captype`

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\makeatletter
\DeclareCaptionFormat{diaa}{\csname\@captype name\endcsname\ \csname the\@captype\endcsname.#1 #2 #3}
\makeatother

\begin{document}



\captionsetup[subfigure]{format=diaa}
\captionsetup[subtable]{format=diaa}

\chapter{Foo}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \subcaption{some subcaption}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{some caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{subtable}{0.5\textwidth}
    \subcaption{some subcaption}
\end{subtable}
\caption{some caption to a table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @DiaaAbidou: You're welcome. Happy TeXing!

Comment: I have another question if you don't mind, how can I revert back to the default format after using this custom one?

Comment: @DiaaAbidou: Try `\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=default}`, please

Comment: It works when using `\captionsetup[subfigure]{format=default}`. Thanks for help.

Comment: @DiaaAbidou: Oh yes, `format`, not `labelformat`, sorry confused it!